# WP Как разложить json и записать его в таблицу БД?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Имееться две кастомные таблици созданные в WordPress :
`wp_sports_viewer` состоящая из трех ячеек
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и `wp_sports_viewer_clear` созданная как:

```
function create_table2()
        {
            global $wpdb;
            require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';
            $table_name2 = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'sports_viewer_clear';
            $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
            if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name2'") != $table_name2) {

                $sql = "CREATE TABLE {$table_name2}
                ( id INT NOT NULL default 0,
                  scheduled TEXT NOT NULL default '0',
                  type TEXT NOT NULL default '0',
                  virtual TEXT NOT NULL default '0',
                  sport_id INT NOT NULL default 0,
                  sport_name TEXT NOT NULL default '0',
                  category_id INT NOT NULL default 0,
                  category_name TEXT NOT NULL default '0',
                  category_sport_id INT NOT NULL default 0,
                  category_country_code TEXT NOT NULL default '0',
                  tournament_id INT NOT NULL default 0,
                  tournament_name TEXT NOT NULL default '0',
                  competitor1_id INT NOT NULL default 0,
                  competitor1_name TEXT NOT NULL default '0',
                  competitor1_abbreviation TEXT NOT NULL default '0',
                  competitor2_id INT NOT NULL default 0,
                  competitor2_name TEXT NOT NULL default '0',
                  competitor2_abbreviation TEXT NOT NULL default '0',
                  market1 TEXT NOT NULL default '0',
                  market11 TEXT NOT NULL default '0',
                  market186 TEXT NOT NULL default '0',
                  PRIMARY KEY (id));
                  {$charset_collate}";
                dbDelta($sql);

                $wpdb->insert(
                    $table_name2,
                    array(
                        'id' => 0,
                        'scheduled' => 'test',
                        'type' => 'test',
                        'virtual' => 'test',
                        'sport_id' => 0,
                        'sport_name' => 'test',
                        'category_id' => 0,
                        'category_name' => 'test',
                        'category_sport_id' => 0,
                        'category_country_code' => 'test',
                        'tournament_id' => 0,
                        'tournament_name' => 'test',
                        'competitor1_id' => 0,
                        'competitor1_name' => 'test',
                        'competitor1_abbreviation' => 'test',
                        'competitor2_id' => 0,
                        'competitor2_name' => 'test',
                        'competitor2_abbreviation' => 'test',
                        'market1' => 'test',
                        'market11' => 'test',
                        'market186' => 'test',
                    )
                );
            }
        }
        create_table2();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача - как полученный `json` которые храниться в `wp_sports_viewer` (ячейка с данными 3.5Мб) разложить по ячейкам созданной таблицы `wp_sports_viewer_clear`?

то что храниться в `json` ячейке таблицы `wp_sports_viewer`

```
{
    \"items\": [
        [
            [
                \"2201519978828664872\",
                \"desc\"
            ],
            {
                \"id\": \"2201519978828664872\",
                \"scheduled\": 1670714400,
                \"type\": \"match\",
                \"virtual\": false,
                \"sport\": {
                    \"id\": \"117\",
                    \"name\": \"MMA\"
                },
                \"category\": {
                    \"id\": \"1669819099414401024\",
                    \"name\": \"UFC\",
                    \"sport_id\": \"117\"
                },
                \"tournament\": {
                    \"id\": \"2195268785794060299\",
                    \"name\": \"UFC 282: Prochazka vs. Teixeira 2\",
                    \"category_id\": \"1669819099414401024\"
                },
                \"competitors\": [
                    {
                        \"id\": \"293764\",
                        \"name\": \"Lawrence, Ronnie\",
                        \"sport_id\": \"117\",
                        \"abbreviation\": \"LAW\"
                    },
                    {
                        \"id\": \"658417\",
                        \"name\": \"Saaiman, Cameron\",
                        \"sport_id\": \"117\",
                        \"abbreviation\": \"SAA\"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        [
            [
                \"2201519978828664872\",
                \"market\",
                \"186\"
            ],
            {
                \"\": {
                    \"4\": {
                        \"k\": \"1.42\"
                    },
                    \"5\": {
                        \"k\": \"2.85\"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        [
            [
                \"2201561636442091568\",
                \"desc\"
            ],
            {
                \"id\": \"2201561636442091568\",
                \"scheduled\": 1668002400,
                \"type\": \"match\",
                \"virtual\": false,
                \"sport\": {
                    \"id\": \"1\",
                    \"name\": \"Football\"
                },
                \"category\": {
                    \"id\": \"1672291833432162304\",
                    \"name\": \"Algeria\",
                    \"sport_id\": \"1\",
                    \"country_code\": \"DZA\"
                },
                \"tournament\": {
                    \"id\": \"1672291833478369280\",
                    \"name\": \"Ligue 1\",
                    \"category_id\": \"1672291833432162304\"
                },
                \"competitors\": [
                    {
                        \"id\": \"42201\",
                        \"name\": \"ASO Chlef\",
                        \"sport_id\": \"1\",
                        \"country_code\": \"DZA\",
                        \"abbreviation\": \"ASO\"
                    },
                    {
                        \"id\": \"42207\",
                        \"name\": \"CR Belouizdad\",
                        \"sport_id\": \"1\",
                        \"country_code\": \"DZA\",
                        \"abbreviation\": \"CRB\"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        [
            [
                \"2201561636442091568\",
                \"market\",
                \"1\"
            ],
            {
                \"\": {
                    \"1\": {
                        \"k\": \"3.35\"
                    },
                    \"2\": {
                        \"k\": \"2.85\"
                    },
                    \"3\": {
                        \"k\": \"2.13\"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        [
            [
                \"2201561636442091568\",
                \"market\",
                \"11\"
            ],
            {
                \"\": {
                    \"4\": {
                        \"k\": \"2.35\"
                    },
                    \"5\": {
                        \"k\": \"1.51\"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        [
            [
                \"2201576548157493255\",
                \"desc\"
            ],
            {
                \"id\": \"2201576548157493255\",
                \"scheduled\": 1667993400,
                \"type\": \"match\",
                \"virtual\": false,
                \"sport\": {
                    \"id\": \"5\",
                    \"name\": \"Tennis\"
                },
                \"category\": {
                    \"id\": \"1669817287911280640\",
                    \"name\": \"ITF Men\",
                    \"sport_id\": \"5\"
                },
                \"tournament\": {
                    \"id\": \"2201245263186767908\",
                    \"name\": \"ITF Tunisia F54, Men Singles\",
                    \"category_id\": \"1669817287911280640\"
                },
                \"competitors\": [
                    {
                        \"id\": \"321665\",
                        \"name\": \"Marmousez, Lilian\",
                        \"sport_id\": \"5\",
                        \"country_code\": \"FRA\",
                        \"abbreviation\": \"MAR\"
                    },
                    {
                        \"id\": \"228372\",
                        \"name\": \"Soriano Barrera, Adria\",
                        \"sport_id\": \"5\",
                        \"country_code\": \"ESP\",
                        \"abbreviation\": \"SOR\"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        [
            [
                \"2201576548157493255\",
                \"market\",
                \"186\"
            ],
            {
                \"\": {
                    \"4\": {
                        \"k\": \"2.47\"
                    },
                    \"5\": {
                        \"k\": \"1.48\"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        [
            [
                \"2201064357406838818\",
                \"desc\"
            ],
            {
                \"id\": \"2201064357406838818\",
                \"scheduled\": 1668348000,
                \"type\": \"match\",
                \"virtual\": false,
                \"sport\": {
                    \"id\": \"1\",
                    \"name\": \"Football\"
                },
                \"category\": {
                    \"id\": \"1669817279438786560\",
                    \"name\": \"Portugal\",
                    \"sport_id\": \"1\",
                    \"country_code\": \"PRT\"
                },
                \"tournament\": {
                    \"id\": \"1669818969340645376\",
                    \"name\": \"Liga Portugal 2 SABSEG\",
                    \"category_id\": \"1669817279438786560\"
                },
                \"competitors\": [
                    {
                        \"id\": \"3037\",
                        \"name\": \"SC Covilha\",
                        \"sport_id\": \"1\",
                        \"country_code\": \"PRT\",
                        \"abbreviation\": \"COV\"
                    },
                    {
                        \"id\": \"3004\",
                        \"name\": \"B-SAD Lisbon\",
                        \"sport_id\": \"1\",
                        \"country_code\": \"PRT\",
                        \"abbreviation\": \"SAD\"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        [
            [
                \"2201064357406838818\",
                \"market\",
                \"1\"
            ],
            {
                \"\": {
                    \"1\": {
                        \"k\": \"2.55\"
                    },
                    \"2\": {
                        \"k\": \"3.3\"
                    },
                    \"3\": {
                        \"k\": \"2.6\"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        [
            [
                \"2201064357406838818\",
                \"market\",
                \"11\"
            ],
            {
                \"\": {
                    \"4\": {
                        \"k\": \"1.83\"
                    },
                    \"5\": {
                        \"k\": \"1.87\"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
```

Что бы каждый раз когда значения в ячейке `json` `wp_sports_viewer` обновлялось, обновлялись и данные в `wp_sports_clear` ?

Мои начальные идеи в создании такой функции. Посоветуйте, как такое решается ?

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_clearDB', 'dataStructuring' );
function dataStructuring(){
    global $wpdb;
    $tb_sports = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'sports_viewer';
    $json = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT json FROM $tb_sports");
    
    global $wpdb2;
    $tb_clear = $wpdb2->get_blog_prefix() . 'sports_viewer_clear';

    $array = json_decode($json, true);
    print $array;


    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: По-моему, надо просто написать запрос, который принимает показанный JSON, парсит его и раскладывает извлечённые значения в правильные поля. Пути внутри JSON известны, так что надо просто проявить немножко терпения и аккуратности. Весьма желательна версия MySQL, понимающая JSON_TABLE() и NESTED PATH в нём (8.0.4 минимум, 8.0.21+ оптимум).

Comment: ИМХО писать в базу json, данные которого требуется менять - не лучшая идея. Уж лучше сериализованный массив, хотя тоже так себе, но хоть вписывается в парадигму ВП. Ну а по задаче - регулярки в руки...

Comment: @Akina Где-то в таком направлении и мыслить) Пока, что все работы ведутся на локальной машине.  И на Apache крутиться MySQL / MariaDB - 10.3  Но поскольку с базами работал очень мало, и это новый язык, хотелось бы хотя бы маленький примерчик как это разпаршивать...

Comment: [JSON_TABLE() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html). Там и подробное описание, и примерчики имеются.